# Xcode CGRECT resize but basline will remain

Tags: xcode

I'm sure this question has been answered 100 times, I just can't figure out how to 'ask' it properly.  When I resize a CGRect object from say 200 high to 100 high, it resizes the box, but moves it to compensate.  Is it possible to change the height of the rectangle but leave the bottom at the same position as before the resize?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Just adjust the `rect.origin.y` at the same time...